# How to rerun testng-failed.xml via maven in the same Jenkins build

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to the Maven and Jenkins, and could not figure out how to:

1. Re-run failed test cases using `testng-failed.xml` through Maven (`pom.xml`) in Jenkins under the same build.
2. Using my automation code, I want to run two different suites i.e. Smoke and Regression present in `smoke.xml` & `regression.xml`.
   I tried putting both xml files under `<suiteXmlFiles>` node, but that is giving me error.

Let me know if I need to create separate Jenkins job for running smoke and regression suites. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
In Pom.xml add two profiles one for regression and other for smoke.Create seperate Jobs in Jenkins for Regression and smoke and configure with corresponding profiles.

Sample Pom.xml profile for regression, do the same for smoke:
<profile>
            <id>REGRESSION</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>${testng.memory.opts}</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>${test.include}</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>${test.exclude}</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>path/Regression-test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>

                            <systemPropertyVariables>

                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                                    <value>false</value>
                                </property>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>${testng.listeners}</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                            <!-- <workingDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/</workingDirectory> -->
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <reporting>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-surefire-report-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${surefire.reports.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </reporting>
        </profile>
```

Comment: Thanks Nisha for your reply, but when I put these changes in my pom.xml, it gives me error. There is no 'profile' tag available in maven; rather its 'profileS'. Also when I try to put <build> tag under <profiles>, it throws many errors saying 'cannot resolve symbol 'atrifactid'', 'cannot resolve symbol 'configuration'' etc.

Comment: please put all your profile tag under profiles tag: <profiles><profile></profile><profile></profile</profiles>